# Error while getting location from Future [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s)

Tags: dart, flutter, geolocation

I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude coordinate of the user, but I'm having trouble accessing those values from Future.

Currently, I'm using the Geolocator package to get a Future, but when retrieving the value I run into an error.

To get the location, this is what I'm doing:

```
Future<Position> locateUser() async {
  return Geolocator()
      .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
      .then((location) {
    if (location != null) {
      print("Location: ${location.latitude},${location.longitude}");
    }
    return location;
  });
}
```

And to retrieve those coordinates, within a build Widget function,
I am doing this:

```
bool firstTime = true;
String latitude;
String longitude;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(firstTime == true) {
      locateUser().then((result) {
        setState(() {
          latitude = result.latitude.toString();
          longitude = result.longitude.toString();
        });
      });
      fetchPost(latitude, longitude);
      firstTime = false;
    }
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s)
```

I want to be able to store those coordinated in variables and pass them into other functions I have. I'm pretty new to Flutter, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your are using an `async` method so you can use `await` keyword to get the response:

Change this

```
            Future<Position> locateUser() async {
              return Geolocator()
                  .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
                  .then((location) {
                if (location != null) {
                  print("Location: ${location.latitude},${location.longitude}");
                }
                return location;
              });
            }
```

To this:

```
            Future<Position> locateUser() async {
              final location = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

              if (location != null) {
                  print("Location: ${location.latitude},${location.longitude}");
               }

              return location;
            }
```

Call `fetchPost(latitude, longitude)` inside your callback and remove your call from build method and move on `initState` method or you can use FutureBuilder.

```
      @override
      void initState() {
        locateUser().then((result) {
            setState(() {
              latitude = result.latitude.toString();
              longitude = result.longitude.toString();
              fetchPost(latitude, longitude);
            });

          });
        super.initState();
      }
```

Comment: I had already tried that actually, but there was no change :(

Comment: The problem seems to be from my fetchPost function (an http request to an api), and using Future Builder solved the problem. Thank anyways!

Comment: @fallingriptide, could you post an example of your solution?  Thanks